# regex for string starts with X and contains Y

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a function that builds a regular expression that can test whether a string starts with a string and contains another string.

```
function buildRegExp(startsWith,contains){
    return new RegExp( ????? )
}
```

for example:

```
buildRegExp('abc','fg').test('abcdefg')
```

The above expression should evaluate to true, since the string 'abcdefg' starts with 'abc' and contains 'fg'.

The 'startsWith', and the 'contains' strings may overlap eachother, so the regular expression cannot simply search for the 'startsWith' string, then search for 'contains' string

the following should also evaluate to true:

```
buildRegExp('abc','bcd').test('abcdefg')
```

I cannot use simple string functions.  It needs to be a regular expression because I am passing this regular expression to a MongoDB query.

Comment: Wait - I don't understand the second part. "bce" isn't in the string.

Comment: I suspect the second example should be `buildRegExp('abc','bcd').test('abcdefg')`

Answer (score 9):

A pattern like this would handle cases where the `startsWith` / `contains` substrings overlap in the matched string:

```
/(?=.*bcd)^abc/
```

i.e.

```
return new RegExp("(?=.*" + contains + ")^" + startsWith);
```

Comment: Was just about to submit an update to my answer, but you got it first. Kudos.

Comment: Interested to see some benchmarking between this and conventional `return s.startsWith(startsWith) && s.contains(contains);`

Comment: +1 for compact and efficient. Been enjoying a cruise through your regex answers, nice work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp

```
(^X).*Y
```

E.g. in javascript

> /(^ab).*bc/.test('abc')  => false
>
> /(^ab).*bc/.test('abcbc') => true

Comment: This doesn't work for the overlapping case. Your first example is supposed to return `true`.